# Encode HTML in SMTP Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, skpsmtpmessage

I am new to trying the SMTPClient and would like to send a HTML formatted email to customers.  The email message instead contains all the tags and not a formatted document.  This is my code:

```
public void SendMailMessage(string FromAddress, string FromName, string ToName, string ToAddress, string Subject)
{
    MailAddress fromAdd = new MailAddress(FromAddress, FromName);
    MailAddress toAdd = new MailAddress(ToAddress);
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(fromAdd, toAdd);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    msg.Subject = Subject;
    string HtmlContent = "<div id='emailFormat' style='width: 100%; background-color: #efeac9;'>" +
                       "< div id = 'emailMsg' style = 'margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 600px; margin-top: 15px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: .9em;' ><h2>Hello World</h2></div></div>");
    msg.Body = HtmlContent;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Send(msg);
}
```

}

The email message looks like this:

> Susan Farrar      Today at 5:45 PM
>   Tosusan.farrar@sbcglobal.net
>
> Message body
>
> < div id = 'emailMsg' style = 'margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 600px; margin-top: 15px; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: .9em;' >
>
> ### Hello World

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespace is causing the issue. You should change this:

```
< div id = 'emailMsg' ...
```

To this:

```
<div id = 'emailMsg' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the content of `string HtmlContent` is not a well-formed HTML document. You are missing tags like `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>`, `<body>`. Also, the additional space in `< div` is incorrect.